# what is best column type for status in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, relational-database

I have status field that can get some values(**not just two**) like: pending,active, inactive, inactive by admin, archived.

what mysql field type should I use for ***performance and readability***?

I found two solution. which of these is better and why?(if any other solution let me know):

1- use **tinyint** and in comment mention that each number is for what

2- use **varchar** and put status directly into it

Comment: The answer is basically dependent on where you are going to use it and how you are going to use it. This would be a primarily opinion based question.

Comment: this could also be an enum, a foreign key on a status table...

Comment: @R.T. what solution is good for what situation? can you explain please

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus another table for status, so need a join, doesn't have performance problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My opinion would be that if you are simply `selecting` the value then it would not matter whether you will use `varchar` or `tinyint`.

But if you are going to use it in some where condition then `tinyint` would have an edge over `varchar`. Also it is recommended to choose the smallest data type possible.

Comment: @mohsenkw:- Then tinyint would be a better choice. As you will get the performance edge for using it.

Comment: @mohsenkw:- Just for your understanding if you are going to use tinyint(5) then it is a small int from 0 to 255 whereas varchar(3) has 3 or more bytes. varchar needs more space anyway. Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you use ENUM.
You can specify a list of values that the field can accept.

However you are going to often change the values you are going to allow and have a large amount of data, using ENUM will a pain.

Comment: ENUM is not a good data type to go for status fields. Avoid it.